# Mac doesn't show Nvidia in Graphics (about this Mac)

Tags: macos, graphics, gpu

Mac doesn't show Nvidia 750M in place of graphics card here. Earlier I had Nvidia showing here instead of Iris Pro

[image]

Comment: I've never checked the About This Mac specifically for the Graphics Info on a dual graphics Mac so it's possible that this info *could* change depending on what chip was active.  A better bet is to run System Report

Comment: System Information app in (Graphics/Displays) lists both...Iris pro and Nvidia 750M

Comment: I don't think it's an issue.  The dual graphics model automatically switches chips depending on what is being done.